# Uploading an image to a server with react-native and expo-image-picker

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development

I am new to React Native and mobile development in general.

I have seen two ways to upload an image to a server demonstrated. These are:

- encoding the image data in base 64 and sending this to a post endpoint which accepts `application/json`, inserting the base 64 encoded data as part of the request body
- using something called `FormData`

I am not sure which of these is the recommended way, or even whether there might be other alternatives.

My objective is to:

- select an image using `expo-image-picker` (I have managed to get this working)
- upload the image to a NodeJS server

I have not been able to get either method to work.

Most recently I tried encoding the data with JSON. This is what my code looks like:

```
const ImageUploadScreen = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const handleImageUploadAsync = () => {
    if (!selectedImage) {
      alert("Please select an image first");
      return;
    }

    const base64Image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${selectedImage.data}`;

    axios
      .post("http://192.168.0.10:3000/upload", {
        image: base64Image,
        filename: "uploaded_image.jpg",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Image uploaded successfully:", response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error uploading image:", error.message);
      });
  };

  const selectImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setSelectedImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    } else {
      alert("no image selected");
    }
  };
}
```

It is fairly obvious why this doesn't work. `selectedImage` is set to a `uri` which is a string value, which obviously does not have a `.data` field.

At this point I am a bit unsure as to how to proceed. One potential option might be to use the `fs` module to read the image data from storage once the `uri` is determined. But this seems like the wrong approach, as the image data on disk will be accessed twice. Once to get the `uri`, which is then used by an `<Image>` element which itself reads the image data, and then once again to get the actual image data to upload.

At the moment I am using the `uri` to display the image inside an `<Image>` React-Native element.

(Basically the image data would be read twice if this approach was used.)

I suppose it doesn't matter that much but this seems inefficient.

I also don't know what to do if the image is not a `jpg`. My example code hardcodes the expected image filename and type to be jpg.

Comment: I would expect the app reads the first time the file/folder structure and the second time the binaries. At this point I wouldn't have any concerns about performance.

Answer (score 0):

It took me several passes (and many days) to pull all the pieces together from many, many code sample to get file uploading working in Expo/React-Native.

The code I came up with is for uploading an expo-image-picker selected image to Firebase Storage, but I suspect it is getting the Blob that is the real "genius" (I'm not the genius...just the hack that got it working).

Here's the code for that is below, where `imagePickerResult` is the returned value from `expo-image-picker`:

```js
// From: https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-firebase-storage-upload/App.js

const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
  };
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.open('GET', imagePickerResult.uri, true);
  xhr.send(null);
});
```

The full code for "upload to Firebase Storage" is [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/gregfenton/f82a953feef12c17fd82f548e60a4c53).